# Jquery Validation - Check word in String

Tags: jquery, validation

With Jquery Validation for Bootstrap plugin, I have a form.

Now that I want to check a field that must contain a specific word. Like

`Field have the word 'COMPLUSORY_WORD' in the string` - return valid

`Field don't have the word 'COMPLUSORY_WORD' in the string` - return invalid

What additional method should I include in validation script?

Comment: dont you want to use javascript? If you want, you can use the `.indexOf` built in function to do just that

Comment: @vance I am using jquery validation plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
if (yourstring.indexOf("COMPLUSORY_WORD") >= 0)
```

You can also make your search case insensitive like this:

```
if (yourstring.toLowerCase().indexOf("COMPLUSORY_WORD") >= 0)
```

**EDIT:**

You can try to use it like this":

```
function checkWord(yourstring, compulsaryword)
{
  return new RegExp( '\\b' + compulsaryword + '\\b', 'i').test(yourstring);
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can try this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('COMPLUSORYWORDCHECK', function (value, element) { 
    return this.optional(element) || /^\bCOMPLUSORY_WORD\b$/.test(value);
}, "Compulsary word");
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way for creating additional validation rule?

Comment: @user3045457:- What do you mean by `additional validation rule`?

Comment: Because I am using jquery validation script like $("#myform").validate(); http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

Comment: @user3045457:- Updated my answer!

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is when I enter some more text with compalsary_word, it returns invalid. I want to check the whole string that must contain specific word and how can I send different compulsary_word to the validator?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. This is my solution to check if the value contains a word out of a chosen list of keywords.
in my case i check if the emailadress contains a valid domain.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("contains",
function (value, element, param) {
    var contains = false;
    for (i = 0; i < param.length; i++) {
        if (value.includes(param[i])) {
            contains = true;
        }
    }
    return this.optional(element) || contains;
},"custon message.");
```

and this is the ruleblock:

```
'altEmail': {
            email: true,
            contains: ["@domain1.ch", "@domain2.ch", "@domain3.ch"]
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to @rahul tripathi's  answer and got what I wanted

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod('COMP_WORD', function (value, element, param) { 
    return RegExp( '\\b' + param + '\\b', 'i').test(value);
}, "Must contain the word PARAMETER_VAL in CAPS");
```